# MPAndroidChart, LineChart setting multiple values on same position of x-axis

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am sharing an example to explain my issue:
I have values like this :
the x-axis is having date values:  6 July, 7 July, 8 July
y-axis is having temperature values :  95,96,97,.....,105.

so now I have 5 temperature inputs for the date 6 July. When I am plotting the graph it showing all the values in a single vertical line with value circles.

What I want that it should connect with each other but should show which value comes first, then second, and so on.

I am sharing the image for both what output I want and as of now what I am getting.

[As of now I am getting output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCRkw.jpg)

But I want output should come like this : [Result should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojTmT.jpg)

this is my code link : [we.tl/t-GkLWefT26F]

Comment: So You need to "tell" which value comes first. Use more specific dates (for example timestamp) for each value, then use formatting on Axis to only show formatted date that shows full days. Currently Your chart takes inputs and they share the same date, so it places them on same date.
Do You use more accurate date internally?

Comment: In our requirement we have to show three date data on graph . If i will define timestamp graph x-axis data will collapse . can you please share any example which can help. It is very urgent.

Comment: Can you please share the snippet of code where you append entries to your ```ArrayList<Entry>()```?

Comment: Try to pass timestamps and then use Formatter and customization to only show those full days. Formatter docs: https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/

Comment: this is my sample project . You can check here for same date data it is plotting single vertical line not showing difference between values.   this is my code link please check and share suggestion.  [code link](we.tl/t-cX1tKkHb0K)